# Simplify incoming Dates and time to Month and Year in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I currently have payments going into a Google Sheet in the current format:

```
Date                      | Company  |   Location       |  Category         | Paid
                          |          |                  |                   |
March 10, 2020 at 12:00PM |xxxx      |55 Street, USA    |Shopping           |$40.65
```

Is it possible to take the date and simplify it down to only the month and year (like "March 2020), I'm using this data in another sheet and simplifying the data by month and category.

Something like this:

```
Date       |  Category         | Paid
           |                   |
March 2020 |Shopping           |$40.65
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a regular expression with `Regexreplace()`

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,",|at.*",)
```

[image]

Comment: That's just what I'm looking for, thank you!